# PyCharm libs (pillow zlib) differs from system ones?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I'm tring (for a few hours) to set up a python dev environment (on win 10), but i really don't get how (AND WHY THIS SO SO COMPLICATED) to install libraries

- Python 3.10 x64
- Pycharm community 2023.2.2

Visible in my Pycharm project settings :

- Pip 23.2.1
- setuptools 68.2
- wheel 0.41.2

I don't get WHY, when i type "pip install PILLOW", from Pycharm terminal, it fails saying :
`The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.`
Causing :
`ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow`

Therefore, when i use a simple cmd (outside pycharm) if i type "pip install PILLOW" it has succeeded ;
if i retype it, it says OK :
`Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)`
So it seems pillow is ok (then zlib could be used !!?) but not usable directly in PyCharm

This seems applyable to other libs...

Why is there several installations of each lib ?
Can't Pycharm use my general installation of pillow ?
Maybe a other free IDE can be more simple to set up ?
Maybe all IDE do these things duplicating libs  ?

I've read i could find zlib by compilating with perl (WHAT ! i wanna dev in python, not perl..)

Thanks to everyone that can help.

Comment: Well, i uninstalled pyCharm since it seems not easy to set up an environment.

I installed Anaconda with the help of Python Simplified on YT : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmgyXK84TR0&ab_channel=PythonSimplified

And everything worked... pillow and pyinstaller ok
I had to use Python 3.11.6, not 3.12.